# How to install "dllcoqrun.so" when trying to build the coq source code?

Tags: coq

I'm trying to build the coq-8.4pl4 from source code, and I run into an error saying "Fatal error: cannot load shared library dllcoqrun Reason: dllcoqrun.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". 
While I know that I should install dllcoqrun.so, but what is dllcoqrun.so and how can I install it?

I'm using ubuntu 18.04, ocaml-4.00.0 and camlp5-rel707

```
COQMKTOP -o bin/coqtop.byte
File "lib/lib.cma(Errors)", line 1:
Warning 31: files lib/lib.cma(Errors) and /usr/local/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs/ocamlbytecomp.cma(Errors) both define a module named Errors
File "pretyping/pretyping.cma(Matching)", line 1:
Warning 31: files pretyping/pretyping.cma(Matching) and /usr/local/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs/ocamlcommon.cma(Matching) both define a module named Matching
File "interp/interp.cma(Lexer)", line 1:
Warning 31: files interp/interp.cma(Lexer) and /usr/local/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs/ocamlcommon.cma(Lexer) both define a module named Lexer
COQC -nois theories/Init/Notations.v
Fatal error: cannot load shared library dllcoqrun
Reason: dllcoqrun.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Makefile.build:494: recipe for target 'theories/Init/Notations.vo' failed
make[1]: *** [theories/Init/Notations.vo] Error 2
```

Comment: Any reason for trying 8.4 in particular? This is a pretty old version, so it wouldn't surprise me if you some effort to setup the build.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I want to compile a project which requires coq 8.4 specifically, so I have to trying 8.4 :)

Comment: Did you notice that the INSTALL file of the distribution has a section dedicated to this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I noticed that the INSTALL file has a section about this problem but the file just told me to install `dllcoqrun.so` and I didn't know how to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, the Coq development team maintains package management instructions to build old versions of Coq in its `opam` package suite.

## With the default installation of opam through apt-get

The experiment in this section was done using a recent version of ubuntu (more precisely, I used a docker image that was downloaded today).  I only had to perform the following steps (the first four were performed as super-user):

```
apt-get -q -y update
apt-get -q -y dist-upgrade
apt-get -q -y install m4 rsync git #not sure this is needed
apt-get -q -y --no-install-recommends install ocaml-nox opam aspcud
```

The following operations were performed as regular user:

```
opam init -a
opam switch 4.00.0
opam install coq.8.4.5
```

the last command will ask a question to which you should answer `y`.

This creates an installation of coq that can be found in the directory `$HOME/.opam/4.00.0/bin`.  To make sure that this version is usable in the current shell, you should execute the following line:

eval $(opam config env)

## With opam version 2

I don't remember how to install `opam` version 2, but it is the version running on my machine.  so for the record, here is what I did to install a slightly different version of coq.8.4.

```
opam switch create for-coq.8.4 ocaml-base-compiler.4.00.0
opam repo add coq-core-dev https://coq.inria.fr/opam/core-dev
opam install coq.8.4.dev
```

If you are reluctant using `opam`, you can actually collect the relevant information from the [following file](https://github.com/coq/opam-coq-archive/tree/master/core-dev/packages/coq/coq.8.4.dev).  I just tried and it works for me, but I am on a Fedora machine and `opam` was already installed.

Look [here](https://opam.ocaml.org/) for more information about `opam`.

Comment: Thank you! Opam just saves me!